# Java EE, communication Web app and Desktop app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have Java Server Faces Web application which needs to call a method in a Desktop application on a network machine. This machine will execute some logic on the particular machine. After this is finished, it should call a method on the Web application to report its status.
Both methods will be `void`'s, but do need parameters.

What is the best way to develop this?
I have considered some options:

- Sockets: I've read multiple posts that you should not use Sockets on a Web application.
- Soap: I can set up a server on the Web app, though not on the Desktop app.
- JCA adapter: I don't have any knowledge with this.

**WebApp**

```
    class WebAppClient {
        public void start(String x, List<String> y) {
            // Call DesktopServer.start(x, y);
        }
    }

    interface WebAppServer {
        public void reportBack(String info);
    }
```

**DesktopApp**

```
    class DesktopClient
        public void reportBack(String info) {
            // Call WebAppServer.reportBack(info);
        }
    }

    interface DesktopServer {
        public void start(String x, List<String> y);
    }
```

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, it will have to communicate and use sockets to do it. So writing your own solution with sockets is not such a bad idea, especially is you jsut need one message in both directions.

Comment: Hmm, how come I've read multiple posts on Stackoverflow stating this should not be the way to go? Is there any securityrisk?

Comment: You just need to understand what you're doing. Of course, if you open many sockets directly from the request-handling threads, and wait for some message to come in on the socket, you're preventing the thread from being used to serve another HTTP request, and you could quickly run out of threads and have a completely unresponsive webapp. OTOH, if you use for example a single, dedicated thread to handle a single socket communication, I don't see how anything bad could happen.

Comment: Let me ask you this, why does the web app have to initiate the call? And do you only ever have one desktop app in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, this is a one-on-one relationship.
My web app will initiate the call because it makes use of a CMS, from this CMS it is possible to execute some testing software on another machine (due to safety reasons). This machine will make use of the most basic Java desktop application to receive messages and based on those messages execute software from command shell. When this software is finished (could be 1 minute, could be 2 hours), the machine will report back to the webserver.

Comment: @Aquillo, from a design point of view, web services are the way to go. The implementation semantics are flexible(Sockets,SOAP,REST, Raw Http). I'm not sure what you mean by "I can't setup a server on the desktop", do you mean you're not allowed? or it's not feasible? I ask as JDK 6 ships with a lightweight http webserver which can act as a lightweight container for either Socket level or HTTP level bridging between your web application and your desktop application

Comment: @kolossus: I have in fact been testing to set up a SOAP-server on a Desktop Application, which should be possible. My IDE (Netbeans) could not detect any SOAP-implementations in this application, but did find them in the Web-application. That's why I thought that SOAP wasn't possible on a Desktop Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about sockets, they are simple to use but many networks block simple TCP sockets and only allow HTTP, and sometimes only via HTTP proxy.

HTTP is the way to go, but HTTP does not allow the server to initiate a conversation, it forces you to work in the request response model.

However, there are some methods that can be used order to overcome this restriction:

- Simple polling: you just poll the server periodically in order to know if you got a new message.
- Long polling: you poll the server but the request stays open until the server has something to say, this is also known as "comet" protocol and there implementations out there like jetty.
- websockets: a feature of html5, that as the name suggests, provides a true bi-directional socket over http. this is not yet supported by all network setups.e.g some proxies will block it.

You should do some research on each method and choose the right one for your case.

Good luck.